# import class defined in same module file?

Tags: python

I have a module file called `mymodule.py`, which contains the following code:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

class bar:
    import foo
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = foo().foo
```

The `__init__.py` file in the same directory has

```
from mymodule import foo
```

From a script in the same directory, I have the following code:

```
from mymodule import bar
```

When I try to run `bar()`, I get the error that `No module named foo`. How can I create an instance of `foo` in `bar` when they are defined within the same module file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes are imported with module name first. However, you don't need to import classes in mymodule from within mymodule, just use it. 
Meaning: remove the import foo line

Comment: Well I'll be doggoned! I've been trying to figure this out for the last hour. Won't let me select your answer for another eight minutes but will return.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to import an object defined in the same module:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 1

class bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = foo().foo
```

The `import` statement is intended for objects defined in *other* files only; you import the names defined in another python file into the current module.