# Importing classes defined in the same module

Tags: python

I am having trouble using my classes that I've defined in a module. I've looked at [this stackoverlfow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762531/import-class-defined-in-same-module-file), and the answer seems to be "you don't need imports." This is definitely not the behavior I'm experiencing. I'm using Python 3.3. Here is my directory structure:

```
root/
    __init__.py
    mlp/
        __init__.py
        mlp.py
        layers/
            __init__.py
            hidden_layer.py
            dropout_layer.py
```

My problem is this: the class defined in `dropout_layer.py` extends the class in `hidden_layer.py`, but when I try to import hidden_layer, I sometimes get an error depending on the directory I execute my code from. For instance, `from layers.hidden_layer import HiddenLayer` then I run my code if I execute it from `root/mlp`. This import does not work, however, if I execute my code from `root`. This is strange behavior to me. How can I get this working correctly?

My only non-empty `__init__.py` file is in `root/mlp/layers/`:

```
# root/mlp/layers/__init__.py
__all__ = ['hidden_layer', 'dropout_layer']
```

Comment: If you execute from root, you would have to do from mlp.layers.hidden_layer import HiddenLayer

Comment: It seems kind of silly to me that the imports are relative to where I execute the code from, especially since the classes are in the same module. Luckily, dmau has a good answer.

Comment: @Max: A module is a file.  If your classes are in different files, they aren't in the same module.  It looks like your files here are in the same *package*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 you can prepend a `.` for an import relative to the location of the current module:

```
from .hidden_layer import HiddenLayer
```

Comment: Cool, worked like a charm. It's strange to me that this isn't mentioned in http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: @Max: Those docs are for the internals of the import system.  The `import` statement itself is described at http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import

Comment: You can enable this in 2.6, too, with `from __future__ import absolute_import`.